# Setting up mirrored RAID on the active disk under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, raid

If I install Windows 7 on a 1TB disk, can I then take another 1TB disk and use it as a RAID mirror?

By this I mean set up softRAID within Windows on the active disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you'll have to convert the disks to "dynamic disks" first. [According to Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757696%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> If you convert the disk containing the boot and system partitions to a dynamic disk, you can mirror the boot and system volumes onto another dynamic disk. Then, if the disk containing the boot and system volumes fails, you can start the computer from the disk containing the mirrors of these volumes. For more information, see Create and test a mirrored system or boot volume.